# differences between pucker and tuck

Tags: differences

What are the differences between pucker and tuck, as verbs?

I found that they can both mean "pull or gather up", "contract". Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some senses of *[tuck](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuck#Verb)* overlap with the sense of *[pucker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pucker#Verb)* (“To pinch or wrinkle; to squeeze inwardly, to dimple or fold”), most do not.  The first sense that wiktionary lists for *tuck* is “To pull or gather up (an item of fabric)”.  Typically a tuck, in the fabric sense, is a fairly neat sewn fold, while a pucker is more likely to be an unsightly wrinkle, eg as when a thread drawn too tightly blotches the appearance of a shirtfront.

The phrasal verb *[pucker up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pucker_up#Verb)* (“To contract a facial feature so as to form wrinkles; used especially of the lips when whistling or kissing”) has no *tuck* counterpart, and wiktionary's sense 8 of *tuck* has no *pucker* counterpart.